# Include html file uploaded by user

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, wildfly-9

This it what I would like to do: A user uploads a bunch of html files as a zip archive. I unzip that archive and display the html content on the website.

For that, I would like to include the html content into a thymeleaf page. I have tried this so far:

```
<div th:include="http://localhost:8181/MySpringApp/uploads/include.html"></div>
<div th:include="@{/uploads/include.html}"></div>
<div th:include="@{~/uploads/include.html}"></div>
```

In all three cases I get the following error (with varying URL):

```
Exception processing template "dashboard": Error resolving template "/uploads/include.html", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (dashboard:40)
```

How would I get this to work? I have only seen examples of including static files from the `template` folder. But that's not what I would like to do.

I am using Wildfly 9 and in the `standalone/data` folder I have created the `uploads` folder.

Answer (score 0):

The code like this should work:

```
<div th:include="@{/uploads/include}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a permisson issue? I'm just wondering because you say that some external user can uploads those files, so you might not have the right permisson to display or use them.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `uploads` folder is under `templates`, insert the HTML as:

```
<div th:insert="~{uploads/include}"></div>
```

Btw, `th:include` is not recommended since Thymeleaf 3.0.